# How to delete an image file which is loaded on a datagridview C#?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I have a datagridview with an image column on my form and I set its value to an image in some folder ..

```
Bitmap PicImage;

PicImage = new Bitmap(ImagePath);
Grid.Rows[i].Cells["ImageColumn"].Value = PicImage;
```

when I want to delete the row ,the image should be deleted too, but I get "the process cannot access the file..." message :

```
File.delete(ImagePath);
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I think you are having permission issues. Please check if the folder has proper Read and Write permission for IISUSER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a file stream to unlock the file , so instead of:

```
PicImage = new Bitmap(ImagePath);
```

use:

```
using (var stream= new System.IO.FileStream(ImagePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    var bmp= new Bitmap(stream);
    PicImage  = (Bitmap) bmp.Clone();
}
```

Comment: This might still give issues... the only completely clean way is to make a bitmap that is not linked to _any_ backing resource (no stream either) and simply _paint_ the image on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to unload the image from the Bitmap and then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest method is to load it without *any* links to files or streams. If it's just for showing on a UI, the simplest way to do this without deep-cloning using `LockBits` is simply to paint it on a new 32BPP ARGB image:

```
Bitmap image;
using (Bitmap tmpImage = new Bitmap(filepath))
{
    image = new Bitmap(tmpImage.Width, tmpImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        gr.DrawImage(tmpImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height));
}
// Bitmap "image" is now ready to use.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code unlinked the datagridview from the image file.

```
Bitmap timage;
                using (Bitmap tmpImage = new Bitmap(tname))
                {
                    timage = new Bitmap(tmpImage.Width, tmpImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(timage))
                        gr.DrawImage(tmpImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, timage.Width, timage.Height));
                }
                fileGridView.Rows[dgIndex].Cells["thumbNail"].Value = timage;
```